# Proof the n-th Sturm-Liouville eigenfunction has n-1 zeros.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, operator-theory, boundary-value-problem

I have done a lot of googling and I can't find a single reference to the proof of the fact that the $n$-th eigenfunction of a regular Sturm-Liouville problem has exactly $n-1$ zeros inside the interval. And I do know the proof that it has at least $n-1$ zeros.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 2 good references (people.cs.uchicago.edu/~lebovitz/Eodesbook/sl.pdf)(http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/rdaileda/teach/s12/m3357/lectures/lecture_4_10_short.pdf.)

Comment: The first link does seem to contain a complete proof, thank you!