# Why does the n-th Sturm-Liouville eigenfunction have n-1 zeros?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenfunctions, sturm-liouville

I know this question is a duplicate of [Proof the n-th Sturm-Liouville eigenfunction has n-1 zeros.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1882951/proof-the-n-th-sturm-liouville-eigenfunction-has-n-1-zeros;) however, the link in that question's comments is broken. Also, having a proper answer to this question somewhere on the math stack exchange would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link from the wayback machine at archive.org . Archive.org is a good place to be able to recover old links. Archive.org is maintained by the US Government. You can enter a link there to find this reference. Amazingly, this PDF was archived:
[https://web.archive.org/web/20220629024106/people.cs.uchicago.edu/~lebovitz/Eodesbook/sl.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20220629024106/people.cs.uchicago.edu/%7Elebovitz/Eodesbook/sl.pdf)

Thanks for the question because the PDF is a useful one. I've saved it myself. Their archive is called the Wayback Machine.